# Django form/formset for a tabular list of forms

Tags: python, django, forms, formset

A picture is worth a thousand words. Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image: tabular_formset]

This is simple enough to do by just **manually creating a table within the template** like so:

```
<form>
  <table class="table">
    <thead><tr><th>{% trans 'Name' %}</th><th>{% trans 'Available Quantity' %}</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for p in products %}
      <tr><td>{{p.name}}</td><td>{{p.available}}</td><td><input name="{{p.id}}" type="number" /></td></tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
<form>
```

However, doing it this way **makes it a hassle to deal with the submitted form data as well as do error validation.**

**I'd prefer to do it in a django form** (formset seems more suitable). I've tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298779/form-or-formset-to-handle-multiple-table-rows-in-django) but that doesn't make what i want any easier to accomplish.

Here's a minified version of my (relevant) models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=50)
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', verbose_name=_("Product"))
    quantity = models.FloatField("Quantity")
```

Is there an **elegant way** to do this in django that I'm not considering?

Comment: Yes, formsets. This is exactly built for what you're talking about: a set of django forms. If it sounds daunting, at first, build one form that does exactly what you need. Get it rendering as you wish. Then, build the formset. Add a for loop to your template iterating through the formset forms instead of your single form. Take it one step at a time.

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita First off thanks for the reply! I gave formsets another try and I'm now mainly puzzled by how to associate each OrderItem form in the formset with a specific Product instance. My first attempt involved passing the products to the formset's  constructor as "initial" data and using form.initial.product.name in the template. This was ugly and it also didn't work "as is" because django doesn't send the initial data with the rest of the form on submission. How would you go about this?

Comment: I'd probably handle that manually in the formset saving logic. `instances = formset.save(commit=False); for item in instances: item.product = product`. Mostly because that's the blanket way to add any custom model save behavior at all.. i don't know if it works in your scenario